# Concatenate columns from different files and compare between files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have two files, namely:

`file1.csv`:

```
"ACCOUNT_ID","CTN","NAME","GATEWAY_GUID","DEVICE_GUID","CATALOG_ID","FW_VERSION","DATE_CREATED","STATUS_ID","LOCATION_CODE","BAN","Market_Area","State","IMEI","HW_MODEL"
"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03","SD0A1B3844",="0100E0102000004","","06/24/2014 19:38:44","0",="0003002008",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824",""
```

and `file2.csv`:

```
account,ban,ctn,first_name,last_name,device_gateway_guid,device_id,device_cat_id,IMEI,device_fw_vrsn,date_created,device_status,subscription_created,subscription_name,subscription_market,date
DL!813269 , 418069632891 , undefined , MUHAMMAD , ANJUM , 313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03, ACFF010904 , 00010907000004 , 351612054025777 ,  , 2015-12-18 19:45:31 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , WAS , undefined
```

I am looking to concatenate the 4th and 5th column of `file1` to

```
313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03SD0A1B3844
```

and the 6th and 7th column of `file2` to

```
313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03ACFF010904
```

Then I want to compare the concatenated string of `file1` to the concatenated string of `file2`; the output should be all the records of `file2` that are not seen in `file1`.

Output for the example:

```
313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03SD0A1B3844
```

Because this is in `file1` and not in `file2`. I care for the records that are in `file1` and not in `file2`.

This is what I have tried:

```
awk -F'[ "]*,[ "]*' 'NR==FNR{a[$6$7];next} (FNR==1) || !($4$5 in a)' file2.csv file1.csv
```

but this generates only about 15,000 records, where I expect about 160,000.

Comment: When reading file 1, create an array whose keys are `$4 $5`. When reading file 2, use `if($6 $7 not in array)` to print the values.

Comment: If you want any more help, you need to post your code. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: SO far, i tried this    awk -F'[ "]*,[ "]*' 'NR==FNR{a[$6$7];next} (FNR==1) || !($4$5 in a)' file2.csv file1.csv          Not sure whether it is retrieving correct results.  Because as per reports it should generate some where 160k records. I am able to retrieve around 15k

Comment: Edit the question, don't put code in the comments.

Comment: You haven't put anything into `a[$6$7]`, so you're not creating the array element.

Comment: Try `a[$6$7] = 1; next`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python (untested):

```
import csv

with open('file1.csv') as i:
    reader = csv.reader(i)
    set1 = set(tuple(line[3:4]) for line in reader)

with open('file2.csv') as i:
    reader = csv.reader(i)
    for line in reader:
        if tuple(line[5:6]) in set1:
            continue
        print(line)
```